# Json info through url php

Tags: php, json, url, undefined-index

I'm trying to get specific data from a Json url but i'm stuck in how to get the data i need. The output of my url looks like:

```
{ 
"dev_settings_device":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_63523C6205B", "name":"settings_device", "internalAddress":"settings_device", "type":"settings_device", "supportsCrc":"49", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_69423C65F08", "name":"HAE_METER_v2", "internalAddress":"10", "type":"HAE_METER_v2", "supportsCrc":"1", "supportedCC":"22 3c 3d 3e 56 60 70 72 7a 86 8b 73", "IsConnected":"1", "HealthValue":"10", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10.1":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_69448735F0E", "name":"HAE_METER_v2_1", "internalAddress":"10.1", "type":"gas", "supportsCrc":"0", "CurrentGasFlow":"0.00", "CurrentGasQuantity":"670.00", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10.2":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_6945CFF5F0E", "name":"HAE_METER_v2_2", "internalAddress":"10.2", "type":"elec", "supportsCrc":"0", "CurrentElectricityFlow":"428.00", "CurrentElectricityQuantity":"49464.00", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10.3":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_69458EC5F0E", "name":"HAE_METER_v2_3", "internalAddress":"10.3", "type":"elec_delivered_nt", "supportsCrc":"0", "CurrentElectricityFlow":"NaN", "CurrentElectricityQuantity":"NaN", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10.4":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_6947CCD5F0E", "name":"HAE_METER_v2_4", "internalAddress":"10.4", "type":"elec_received_nt", "supportsCrc":"0", "CurrentElectricityFlow":"NaN", "CurrentElectricityQuantity":"NaN", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10.5":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_694D7AB5F0E", "name":"HAE_METER_v2_5", "internalAddress":"10.5", "type":"elec_delivered_lt", "supportsCrc":"0", "CurrentElectricityFlow":"NaN", "CurrentElectricityQuantity":"NaN", "location":"(null)"},
"dev_10.6":{"uuid":"eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_6941EFB5F0E", "name":"HAE_METER_v2_6", "internalAddress":"10.6", "type":"elec_received_lt", "supportsCrc":"0", "CurrentElectricityFlow":"NaN", "CurrentElectricityQuantity":"NaN", "location":"(null)"}
}
```

My file looks like this

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/* Written by Ierlandfan */
/* 1-11-2015 */
/* Version 1.1 */

/* Change ip_toon to the IP of your Toon */ 
/* start of current Energy usage import */
$file_string_gas = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.66/hdrv_zwave?
action=getDevices.json');
$parsed_json = json_decode($file_string_gas, true);
var_dump($parsed_json['dev_10.1']);

/* Create new virtual sensor and write down the idx value */
/* Define idxvalue here */
$gasUsage=$parsed_json['CurrentGasQuantity'];
$idx = 933;

/* If this script is not run locally on the Domoticz server change 127.0.0.1  
according to your Domoticz IP */
/* Send currentUsage to Domoticz */
$gasusage = curl_init("http://192.168.1.27:8080/json.htm?
type=command&param=udevice&idx=$idx&nvalue=0&svalue=$gasUsage");
curl_exec($gasusage);
echo $gasUsage; 
?>
```

The output i get from the var dump is:

```
array(8) {
  ["uuid"]=>
  string(39) "eneco-001-018946:hdrv_zwave_69448735F0E"
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "HAE_METER_v2_1"
  ["internalAddress"]=>
  string(4) "10.1"
  ["type"]=>
  string(3) "gas"
  ["supportsCrc"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["CurrentGasFlow"]=>
  string(4) "0.00"
  ["CurrentGasQuantity"]=>
  string(6) "670.00"
  ["location"]=>
  string(6) "(null)"
```

The error i receive is: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: CurrentGasQuantity in /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/php/gas_data_json1.php on line 16, but for the life of me i don't understand why. I tried a couple of thing but it seems i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor mistake :

correction , 
`$gasUsage= $parsed_json['dev_10.1']['CurrentGasQuantity']`

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentGasQuantity` is index of `$parsed_json['dev_10.1']`. So you can retrieve it as below :

```
$gasUsage= $parsed_json['dev_10.1']['CurrentGasQuantity']
```